# the datepicker is not working in my bootstrap form i.e the script tags are not getting excuted

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-datepicker

the script tags are not getting executed for the date picker to work properly
this code snippet is from a ejs file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="slot_date"]'); //our date input has the name "slot_date"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        })
    })

</script>
```